# Is it possible to setup a transparent virtual file system (VFS) in userspace?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse, overlayfs

I'm trying to setup a virtual file system (VFS) that is transparent to the final program, where I may need to overlay thousands (1000-2000) of read-only directories and a single copy-on-write one;

currently the only ideas that come to my mind for doing something like this are a custom FUSE or an overlay-fs; from what I understand FUSE tends to be pretty slow so it may not be the best solution, but I have no idea if an overlay-fs could even handle such large amounts of overlayed directories.

Are there any other solutions that I missed for doing this kind of overlaying?
Has anyone ever attempted something like this?

(it would be a plus if it could be setup by non-root users, but not a requirement)

Comment: you can have a look at the Device Mapper which supports snapshot copy on write on the block layer, but it does not handle individual files, you only get that with FUSE

Comment: yeah device mapper doesn't seem useful at all, it's for a very different use case.